# How do I exit the T-45 power armor again?

Tags: fallout-4

I just killed a bunch of Raiders using the power armor and a minigun, but now I can't figure out how to leave the armor again. As it drains power and is rather unwieldly I don't want to continue using it right now.

The Settings menu is no help, I can't find any key assigned to leaving the armor again. So, how exactly do I exit the power armor?

Answer (score 27):

With the default mappings:

- Xbox: press and hold <kbd>A</kbd>
- Playstation: press and hold <kbd>X</kbd> (Cross button).
- PC: press and hold <kbd>E</kbd>.

Source is [this reddit Fallout 4 post](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3s5cbw/how_do_you_exit_your_power_armor/) and [this guide](http://attackofthefanboy.com/guides/fallout-4-guide-how-to-get-out-of-power-armor/).

Comment: In hindsight, it appears Jonathan Drapeau also linked to the source I've used, but in fairness, I did look it up myself...

Comment: That should read on XBox press and hold A and more than likely X for playstation

Comment: Ah, thanks. And thank you as well, @zero298

Comment: For wondering PC users: LONG press E. :P

Comment: Fixed That For You. :3

Comment: Some other useful Press-and-Hold gestures for those curious:

Flashlight: Hold the pipboy button: `B/Circle/Tab`
Holster your weapon: Hold the reload button: `X/Square/R`
Move items/bodies: Hold the pick-up button: `A/Cross/E`
Quickly exit a computer terminal: Hold the exit button: `B/Circle/Tab`
Enter VATS with no enemies nearby: Hold the VATS key: `LB/D-Up/Q`

Grab all attached items in the builder: Hold the grab button: `A/Cross/E`
Raise/Lower items in the builder: Hold `A+L-R/Cross+L1-R1/E+scrollwheel`

PC Special: Use WASD instead of Arrows for Crafting and Dialogue options: Hold `Shift`

Comment: A few more: When hiding behind cover, hold the Aim button `LT/L2/Rightclick` to peek out from cover and shoot at the enemies. Let it go to duck back behind cover.
When looking at your pipboy, hold the Aim button `LT/L2/Rightclick` to look at it from various angles.
When armed with grenades, hold the Melee button `RB/R1/Alt` to throw them.